# Import Snippets in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, joomla, import, code-snippets

i use Eclipse PDT to develop a joomla Component.
i've find [this](http://www.theartofjoomla.com/snippets.html) snippets ed would like to import it in eclipse.

When i import it, nothing happens.
i Extract the xml file from archive file.

Any suggestions?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried downloading the raw view, openening in your text editor and then changing the encoding to UTF-16 BE as suggested in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the encoding in the imported XML file must match the setting you've specified in your Eclipse "Preferences -> General -> Workspace" setting.

Answer (score 1):

Snippets exported by eclipse on my machine where encoded in utf16le; to find out what encoding was used I used the following command:

> file -bi snippet.xml
>   application/xml; charset=utf-16le

The snippets xml files I downloaded where encoded in us-ascii. I converted them to utf16le using the following command:

> iconv -f us-ascii -t utf16le snippet.xml > snippet_utf16le.xml

NB:

1. to print a list of all available encodings use:

   > iconv -l
2. some text editors don't read utf16le it seems; leafpad on ubuntu saw the file as blank when gedit read it fine.

ALTERNATIVELY:

1. export a snippet from eclipse
2. delete the content of the snippet and paste your own code
3. Import the now modified .xml file into snippets

This comment from "Valentin Despa" on the following dicussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/EHkwx9e2R5Y helped me investigate the solution I talked about earlier:

> The files provided by Andrew seem to be encoded in ANSI. My Eclipse exports snippets encoded in UCS-2 Big Endian.
>   With a tools like Notepad++ I've managed to convert them to UCS-2 Big Endian (Encoding > Convert to UCS-2 Big Endian) and worked without any problems.